# Why does Left Outer Join not work for attribute in different types in the tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.

**E_Tab**

```
E_NO E_Code Minutes
170   01    1506
170   40    480
464   01    1440
464   51    1440
464   40    480
```

Second table,
**P_Tab**

```
P_No P_Code Minutes
170   01    1506
170   40    480
464   01    1440
464   51    1440
```

What I want is simply to perform a left outer join. I ran this query:

```
select * from E_Tab e 
left outer join P_Tab p 
    on e.E_No=p.P_No;
```

And getting output:

```
E_NO E_Code Minutes  P_No P_Code Minutes
170   01    1506    null  null   null
170   40    480     null  null   null
464   01    1440    null  null   null
464   51    1440    null  null   null
464   40    480     null  null   null
```

Could anyone please suggest what is going wrong? How can I get the out in the way Left outer join generally works? Thank you.

Edit 1:
E_No is in Number and P_No is in varchar2. E_code and P_code are in same datatyep so as Minutes. Can anybody suggest how to modify the query to get the same intended result?

Edit 2:
My Intended output:
`E_NO E_Code Minutes  P_No P_Code Minutes
    170   01    1506    170  01   1506
    170   40    480     170  40   480
    464   01    1440    464  01   1440
    464   51    1440    464  51   1440
    464   40    480     null  null   null`
Sorry for the confusion. My query may not be correct.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: it seems to work correctly...

Comment: Is there a type error on your output about column E_Code?

Comment: E_No is in Number and P_No is in varchar2. How to fix it?

Comment: If E_NO is NUMBER and P_NO is VARCHAR2 it should work (on Oracle 11).  Can you post create table script?

Comment: Is it possible that you omit a clause on join in the query you posted (eg. AND E.Code = P.Code) while the one you used to generate output has it?

Comment: See my answer: you should add AND E.Code = P.Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated version (assuming that p_code and e_code are VARCHAR):**

```
soelect * 
from E_Tab e
  left outer join P_Tab p
  on e.E_No=p.P_No
   AND SUBSTR(E.E_CODE,2,99) = P.P_CODE
```

Output:

```
E_NO    E_CODE  MINUTES P_NO    P_CODE  MINUTES
1   170 001 1506     170        01  1506
2   170 340 480  170        40  480
3   464 001 1440    464         01  1440
4   464 051 1440    464         51  1440
5   464 340 480 NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**Precedent answer**

Your posted query should work if e_no is NUMBER and p_no is CHAR or VARCHAR, with or without embedded spaces.
I think you didn't post the query you are using.
I can guess from your expected output you forgot

```
 AND E.E_Code = P.P_Code
```

or, if you sample data are correct:

```
 AND SUBSTR(E.E_CODE,2,99)=P.P_CODE
```

in you join clause.
Moreover, the value of E_CODE in your sample output is not the same in your sample data.

Example of output with your query and data, using P_NO as CHAR(8) with spaces:

insert into p_tab values (' 170  ' ,  01,    1506)

```
+--+------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
|  | E_NO | E_CODE | MINUTES |  P_NO   | P_CODE | MINUTES |
+--+------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
|  |  170 |    340 |     480 |  170    |      1 |    1506 |
|  |  170 |      1 |    1506 |  170    |      1 |    1506 |
|  |  170 |    340 |     480 |  170    |     40 |     480 |
|  |  170 |      1 |    1506 |  170    |     40 |     480 |
|  |  464 |    340 |     480 |  464    |      1 |    1440 |
|  |  464 |     51 |    1440 |  464    |      1 |    1440 |
|  |  464 |      1 |    1440 |  464    |      1 |    1440 |
|  |  464 |    340 |     480 |  464    |     51 |    1440 |
|  |  464 |     51 |    1440 |  464    |     51 |    1440 |
|  |  464 |      1 |    1440 |  464    |     51 |    1440 |
+--+------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Okay. Yes. But see mismatching columns are not coming as null.

Comment: And so?  The query as you posted works.  Check what you are doing and check values you posted.

Comment: Yes the query may work. But It does not matter. As I was getting error I couldn't realize about the output. I need a different output. Query may need to be modified. Thanks anyway.

Comment: See what I added in my answer

Comment: I appreciate your effort. It seems quite correct. E_code and P_code are same actually. sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

> "E_No is in Number and P_No is in varchar2. How to fix it?"

`p_no` is a string so the problem could be stray spaces. In which case you can fix that by trimming the column and casting it to a numeric data type.

```
select * from E_Tab e
  left outer join P_Tab p
   on e.E_No= to_number ( trim (p.P_No)) ;
```

Comment: `e.E_No= to_number ( trim (p.P_No))` this part is working. But I am not getting the intended output with null values in mismatching columns.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE CAST( ' 170 ' AS VARCHAR2(10) ) = 170;` will return one row. Oracle should perform an implicit type conversion to a `NUMBER` and the leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of one column is `CHAR` then it will be right-padded with spaces to fill the size of the column.

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE CAST( '9' AS VARCHAR2(10) ) = CAST( '9' AS CHAR(10) );
```

Will return zero rows as `'9'` and `'9         '` are not equal according to Oracle's blank-padded comparison semantics.

The documentation of [blank-padded comparison semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#BABJJGBI) states:

> With blank-padded semantics, if the two values have different lengths, then Oracle first adds blanks to the end of the shorter one so their lengths are equal. Oracle then compares the values character by character up to the first character that differs. The value with the greater character in the first differing position is considered greater. If two values have no differing characters, then they are considered equal. This rule means that two values are equal if they differ only in the number of trailing blanks. Oracle uses blank-padded comparison semantics only when both values in the comparison are either expressions of datatype **`CHAR`**, **`NCHAR`**, text literals, or values returned by the **`USER`** function.

In the example above, the left-hand side of the comparison is a `VARCHAR(10)` and the right-hand side is `CHAR(10)` then blank-padded comparison semantics are not used.

**Update**:

> `E_No` is in Number and `P_No` is in varchar2.

Oracle should perform an implicit type conversion in the equality check and it should work.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE CAST( '170' AS VARCHAR2(10) ) = 170
SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE CAST( ' 170' AS VARCHAR2(10) ) = 170
SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE CAST( '170 ' AS VARCHAR2(10) ) = 170
SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE CAST( '170' AS CHAR(10) ) = 170
```

Will all return one row.

Comment: I understood the problem. Is there any way to fix it like typecasting temporarily only for a query?